# Why doesn't Keep.None affect the Akka stream execution result?

Tags: scala, f#, akka-stream

I have a simple test code for Akka Streams (written in F# but Scala version isn't match different):

```
    var source = Source.From(Enumerable.Range(1, 3));
    var flow = Flow.FromFunction(new Func<int, string>(x => (x * 2).ToString()));
    var sink = Sink.ForEach<string>(output.Add);
    var runnable = source.Via(flow).To(sink);
```

Since Via helper method is just a shortcut for ViaMaterialized(flow, Keep.Left) I can rewrite the code like this:

```
var source = Source.From(Enumerable.Range(1, 3));
var flow = Flow.FromFunction(new Func<int, string>(x => (x * 2).ToString()));
var sink = Sink.ForEach<string>(output.Add);
var runnable = source.ViaMaterialized(flow, Keep.Left).To(sink);
```

Keep property (Left, Right, Both or None) tells the stream materializer that is should preserve the value on a specified side of the stream operation. But I notice that if I change Keep.Left to Keep.Right, Keep.Both or event Keep.None, that doesn't change anything in the execution outcome: the sink will always receive the output according to the flow transformation function.

I thought that using non-None Keep value for Flow stages in a stream graph is necessary to ensure the values gets sent to the sink. I must have misunderstood the meaning of this, so my question is why a stream flow works even when materialization is disabled for both sides? And can you give an example when changing Keep values between Left, Right, Both and None affects the values that reach the sink?

Comment: These code snippets are in C#, not F#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing the fact that a stream gets materialized and the fact that it has a materialized value.

A flow (or more generally a graph) is a blueprint for a stream. When you use the `run()` method on a runnable graph, a stream is materialized using this blueprint. This stream does whatever is expected of it without any regards for materialized values.

What is a materialized value? When you use the method `run()`, a value is returned. That's the materialized value for your stream. Most of the time (for simple built-in stages), the materialized value is unimportant (it's called `NotUsed` in scala, I don't know about .NET). A non-trivial example is the `Sink.ignore` that is materialized as a `Future[Done]`. It gives you a handle on when the particular stream you have materialized will have completely consumed its input (or thrown an error). More generally, the materialized value gives you some circumstantial information on what's going in your stream (sorry about the vagueness of this statement, but the principle at hand is too general for me to be more explicit).

When building a graph, you put together different pieces that all have a different materialized value. Since you can only have one for your runnable graph, you need to combine them in some way. `Keep.{right, left, both, none}` are simple functions that combine those values by keeping only one of the values, or both, or none. However, it does not change the fact that both graphs will be materialized, and the values generated, even if you decide not to keep them.

Comment: Thank you. I confused different things indeed. Now it's clear.

Answer (score 4):

`Keep.*` functions don't influence the materialization process itself, only what you get out of it.

More specifically, at materialization time (i.e. when `run()` is called), each and every stage of your stream (in your example, source, flow and sink) will **always** be materialized - and therefore produce a materialized value under the hood. You can clearly see what that value will be from their last type parameter.

For the user's convenience, as most likely you will not be interested in all of them, you can use `Keep.*` accordingly to select what to *keep* around. This directly reflects on the return type of `run()`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.